# Is it correct to save OAuth tokens in sessions?

Tags: php, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-php-client

I'm wondering if it's a good idea to save access tokens in session.

I am developing an application that requires the Google OAuth Access Token (following [docs](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#example)) to use Calendar.

```php
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfig('credentials.json');
$client->setAccessType('offline');
$client->addScope(Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR_EVENTS);

$redirect_uri = 'https://...';
$client->setRedirectUri($redirect_uri);
if (! isset($_GET['code'])) {
  $auth_url = $client->createAuthUrl();
  header('Location: ' . filter_var($auth_url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
} else {
  $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
  $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
  header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}

$client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['accessToken']);

/* Refresh token when expired */
if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
    // the new access token comes with a refresh token as well
    $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
}
$service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);
...
```

Not always the user will be logged into my site, so I have no way to identify the user, so is it a good practice to save the token in the session?
When I can identify him, can I save his token to the database, or is it better to follow the pattern and leave everything in session?

Comment: You can save it if you want its only going to be good for an hour. Personally i save the refresh token and then just request a new access token when i need it.

Comment: But, if you don't knows the user, how do you save the refresh token?

Comment: If you have a refresh token then you know who the user is.  Just query the userinfo endpoint with the access token it will tell you who the user is.  Not that you need it really.

Comment: By "not knowing" the user, I mean not knowing if he or she or anyone is accessing the site as it can be used without identification. The flow is:
The person enters the site, clicks the "Add to Calendar" button.

So what I thought is:
When not identified, save in the session, when logged in, put in the database, because I know who to assign. Or in this case, the ideal is every time the button is clicked, generate a new token? What do you think?

Answer (score 2):

User sessions can be structured in any way you'd like.

Your objective is to use the right OAuth Token for the right user.

You could do this by creating a Session for the user and storing the token there, however, those sessions might expire earlier than the tokens you are storing in them.

You could also store your refresh tokens in your database and just store a reference number (a custom ID) that helps you tie that session with the user you are serving. This can be useful if you already have a user-account structure in place.

This [official documentation](https://oauth.net/articles/authentication/) is an interesting read if you want to understand more about your situation.